# How to open old light fixture

Tags: light-fixture

I have an old light fixture I'm trying to open, but I cannot figure out how to do it. It's placed quite close to the ceiling which also makes it difficult to get a good look at it.

I've trying push a screw driver in several places, but apart from where the wires can be seen and the two holes on each side it seems to be one piece of plastic.
I cannot see or find anything useful from the holes on each side.

I've also tried twisting the entire thing, but it doesn't seem to move at all.

Does anyone know how to open it?

[image: Bottom of fixture]

[image: Bottom of fixture]

[image: Front of fixture]

[image: Side of fixture]

[image: Side of fixture]

[image: Top of fixture]

[image: Top of fixture]

Comment: What happens if you stick a couple of screwdrivers in those holes, and pry?

Comment: So far, nothing happens. However, it is difficult for me to determine if I just need to use more force or if that will just break it. If I cannot figure out the "right" way, I will most likely end up trying that even if it breaks it - and then afterwards figure out how to put a new fixture there.

Comment: Have you tried rotating?  Get yourself a piece of cardboard to protect it, and a large set of vise grips (or maybe a pipe wrench would work).

Comment: A strap wrench may work better for attempting to rotate it.

Comment: Is it powered? Have you probed it with a non contact voltage tester? What country is this? What is that crusty light colored material in the center of the front?

Comment: You posted 7 photos of something and I still can't tell what I'm looing at. How about a photo of the _whole thing_? I'm not even sure that should open.

Comment: Are there wires on the other side of the steel material it is attached to?

Comment: Those side ports look like this is for surface mounting. Ajunction box for wires running on the surface, of which there do not appear to be any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect it to either twist or pry loose, but it's obviously been painted to the point that it will be difficult to get it to move, making the diagnosis of whether you need to twist harder or pry rather difficult.

I also have doubts about calling it a light fixture - it appears to be simply a point from which a cut-off cord used to dangle a light.

My sure-fire approach would be to buy a complete replacement, make sure power is off, and remove it without regard for it remaining re-usable (thus, quite possibly destructively.) That might involve slip-joint pliers, hammers, or other implements of destruction.

If you have some desire to preserve its painted-over-ancientness, remove the paint and look for clues, but probably the paint that's causing problems is in between the part that stays and the part that comes off and won't be removable until it comes apart, so unless removing the paint reveals a now-hidden-by-layers-of-paint screw, I doubt it will lead to easy removal.

Comment: You are probably right about it not being a light fixture, but that is due to my English. What is the right name for such a thing?

Comment: Perhaps run a knife blade around the that seam and try to unscrew it?